# Loading CSV file with Different Rows/Columns C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, csv

This might be a silly question, not too great with loading files but needed help with loading in csv files that have a different number of elements in rows and columns. Would it be better to store in an array or list and how would i do this?
Example

```
25     ,     15   ,    20  
apple  ,  
tree   ,  
carrot ,  
walking,  
etc..
```

where the numbers are the column and words the rows.

I have tried something like this based on some other answers but it crashes saying that i have not referenced an object. Any suggestions?

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
String[,] wordlist = null;
int Row = 0;
while(!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    String[] header = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
    wordlist[Row, 0] = header[Row];
    Row++;
}
```

Comment: String[,] wordlist = null; is you problem, your 2D array is not initialised which is what throw the exception. it should read             String[,] wordlist = new String[YOUR_LENGTH, YOUR_LENGTH];

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check but believe that it works

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
// String[,] wordlist = null;
var wordList = new List<string[]>();
//int Row = 0;
while(!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    String[] header = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
    //wordlist[Row, 0] = header[Row];
    wordList.Add(header); 
    //Row++;
}
```

Comment: That does work! strangely it does not read out the file correctly i checked the csv is visual studio and the list seems to go like this word,,, otherword,,, is there a way to just read rows?